# is it possible to add a permission to only one user , without creating role for him?

Tags: 7, users

i'm trying to create drupal 7 module for online payment , it will be by roles , for exemple ( user1 can create 'Blog content type' just if he has the permission on that) so after the payment i want to add that role to that user so i can avoid the each time creating roles for the users

thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Ubercart this would be super easy by using hook_order through your own module: http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_order. I do this exact same thing with one of my other sites.

I can't go into it all, but essentially it flows like:

```
//make sure the order is complete and payment is received: 

function sitetheme_order($op, &$arg1, $arg2) {
{
 // on the final update check this order
 if ($op == 'update' &&
     $arg1->order_status == "payment_received" &&
     $arg2 == "completed")
 {
```

In order to keep this short I can't include everything, but I have short loop written that loops through the order until it meets a condition like "Tickets". Then, I'll assign a role and do some other stuff. Like:

```
//If they bought tickets, assign them the role "TicketHolder"
if ($node->type == 'tickets') {
  //I assign some vars, for example the ID of the user role:
   $ticketUser = $node->uid; 
   $customerRole = 16;
   //Assign this user the "TickHolder" role after the sale is complete
       $data = array(
       'uid' => $ticketUser,
       'rid' => $customerRole,
        );
   drupal_write_record('users_roles', $data);
```

That would be it. In your case you check to see if they purchased rights to create blog content, then assign the role.

Comment: tnks for the reply, in one way or another it is helpful for me ,as i understand that the Ubercart is providing some existing methods of payment,in my case i"m living in morocco and to ensure the payment it is necessarily to parse my data into a site called(maroctelecommerce.com)based for security reasons and then the site will provide the users the payment methods , after that the site will send me some encrypting post variables telling me what happened there(if the payment is success or failed )  , i'll be happy to know from you if the Ubercart give us the possibilty to do things like this